# How to set a timeout on a BufferedReader with a socket stream

Tags: java, sockets

Here I am creating a thread to check for a server response every 2 seconds, the issue is that the `client.monitorResponse()` is a `readLine()` method and will not continue until a response is received.

```
client = new ClientObject("localhost");
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            String response = null;
            if(!(response = client.monitorResponse()).isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Response: " + response);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}, 2000, 2000);
```

I am sending the response via the Server like so (where `client` is a established Socket):

```
public SocketObject(Socket client, int numberOfClients) throws Exception {
    socket = client; // the .accept() socket is passed through
    // this is because I assign them ID's for later use (I hold an ArrayList of sockets)
    this.clientId = numberOfClients;

    // both these are static to the class

    outputStream = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());
    inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
}

public void sendResponse(String response) {
    outputStream.println(response);
}
```

I am then picking the response up via the client Socket that has connected to the server:

```
public ClientObject(String hostname) throws IOException {

    // socket is static to this class

    socket = new Socket(hostname, 4444);
    System.out.println("Connected to " + hostname + " on port 4444...");

    // both static to this class

    outputStream = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    System.out.println("Successfully started a stream on " + hostname);
    this.hostname = hostname;
}

public String monitorResponse() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Listening for a response...");
    return inputStream.readLine();
}
```

The debug console only displays the *Listening for a response...* output once which is telling me that it doesn't get past the `inputStream.readLine()` method in-side the Thread. Is there anyway I can add a timeout on the BufferedReader? I have tried multiple solutions like adding a `.setSoTimeout()` to the socket before creating the BufferedReader but all that did was close the connection/socket after the specified time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why? If the server is sending a response, you must read it. If you implement a timeout, the response will be read next time, which will confuse your code. Is the response optional? In which case you've mis-designed your application protocol. And if you're running this code via a `Timer` you don't need a timeout at all. The timer task doesn't have anything else to do but block. As a matter of fact you don't even need the timer, just a thread with a read loop. You're wearing belt and braces here.

Comment: Yeah, I realized it couldn't read the request: that is what was causing the issue. I was missing a second parameter in the `new PrintWriter()` which had to be set to true on the Server where I was using `getOutputStream()` inside it on the Socket. @EJP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a non-blocking (NIO) request and read chunks looking for newlines in-between. Typically in Java you just have to look for the NIO version of the Stream class you are using and use it to check every N seconds for new content. In your case with minimal modifications you can use the less fancy and efficient method of blocking calls with `BufferedReader.ready()` to prevent blocking:

```
String partialLine="";
public static String monitorResponse() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Listening for a response...");
    int nextByte;
    String nextChar;
    while (inputStream.ready()) {
        nextByte = inputStream.read();
        nextChar = Character.toString ((char) nextByte);
        partialLine += nextChar;
        if ("\n".equals(nextChar)) {
            String line = partialLine;
            partialLine = "";
            return line.replace("\r\n", "");
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Check out http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/nio-vs-io.html for more info.

Comment: There is nothing here that implements a timeout. It also doesn't handle `\r\n` correctly, unlike `readLine()`.

Comment: Re your now-deleted comments, it doesn't handle `\r\n` correctly becuse it returns the `\r` in the data, unlike `readLine()`, which removes it. `readLine()` handles all possible cases of line termination. Your code doesn't. My answer doesn't close the connection, and setting a read timeout is exactly what he asked for.

Comment: Tested and updated. Apart from the EOL not being removed as `BufferedReader.readLine()` does, a couple of syntax errors to fix before compiling and a `return ""` required instead of `return null`, this works as expected: The server tries to read a line every 2 seconds. If a full line is not available yet, it tries again 2 seconds later. If more than one line is available, it reads them in order of arrival with a 2 second delay in between. I removed the if condition because it was redundant.

Comment: Yes, I deleted those comments because I realized what you meant by it. It still doesn't handle the EOL perfectly but it could be enough depending on the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway I can add a timeout on the BufferedReader?

No, but you can set a timeout on the `Socket`, with `Socket.setSoTimeout()`.

> I have tried multiple solutions like adding a .setSoTimeout() to the socket before creating the BufferedReader but all that did was close the connection/socket after the specified time.

No it doesn't close the socket. It throws `SocketTimeoutException`, which you should catch and handle as pertinent. If the socket is being closed, you're closing it. Solution: don't.

Comment: I figured it out, I was missing the second boolean parameter on the `new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())` which should of been set to `true` but thanks!

Comment: There is no boolean second parameter on `new InputStreamReader()`.

Comment: EJP you're right. This solution is blocking for 2s when there is no data available but a timeout *is* what the OP asked for. I am the one who should have read the question more carefully. My apologies.